# What does Screen Time limit?

Tags: youtube, parental-controls, children

When you allow 15 minutes for, say, YouTube, does the clock only run while the child watches YouTube or will YouTube time out after 15 minutes even if they don't watch it?

Comment: Screen time works on iOS and macos. Can you add a screen shot on which system and setting you have configured this tool?